# how should i deploy resources like icons?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded-resource

What is the best practice for deploying / packaging resources like icons?  I'd like to avoid loose files due to the number of icons. Can I create a "resource" dll in visual studio? If so, is this the best way to go? What is the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, embedded resources are the way to go.

See [Adding a file to a project, that will be added to the exe, and be accessable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287396/adding-a-file-to-a-project-that-will-be-added-to-the-exe-and-be-accessable-at-r) and [Example code required for how to access embedded .Net image resources in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154262/example-code-required-for-how-to-access-embedded-net-image-resources-in-c) for details.